# how to pass an NSNotification as parameter to the selector function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotifications

I'm trying to implement an `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` to handle my view position when the keyboard appear. 
I add my observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Then I have the `keyboardWillShow` function:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    //Need to access to the notification here
}
```

In the function `keyboardWillShow` I need to receive the `NSNotification` to get access to the user information but I get this error:

> "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd993e7d020"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the colon `:`.  Change it to this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I needed to add the colons in swift I have other observers and they work perfect without the colons but i don't need any parameter from them.

Comment: Yea, you only need the colon if you want the argument :)